# running commands/removing folders through paramiko

Tags: python, bash, sftp, paramiko

I can't run some commands through. For example, rm or rmdir.

I'm trying to remove a folder through paramiko, and I get "Command not found". But "ls -l" command works fine. Also the bash script works fine.

```py
key = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file(RSA_KEY)

with paramiko.SSHClient() as client:
    client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    client.connect(pkey=key, **SERVER_CONN)

    command = "rm /home/request_files/temp/*"

    in_, out_, err_ = client.exec_command(command=command)
    for i in out_:
        print(i)
```

"Command not found"

```py
key = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file(RSA_KEY)

with paramiko.SSHClient() as client:
    client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    client.connect(pkey=key, **SERVER_CONN)

    command = "ls"

    in_, out_, err_ = client.exec_command(command=command)
    for i in out_:
        print(i)
```

dir1

dir2

dir3

etc.

Also i have a bash script, which works fine:

```sh
sftp -P ${SERVER_PORT} ${SERVER_USERNAME}@${SERVER_HOST} <<EOF
    rm ${dir1}/*
    rmdir ${dir1}
EOF
```

Comment: Perhaps you can use paramiko's SFTP features for file system operations: see e.g. http://docs.paramiko.org/en/2.6/api/sftp.html#paramiko.sftp_client.SFTPClient.rmdir

Comment: @furas, I don't get Traceback, program exit with 0 code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @martyn i find the way to solve that problem

```
def open_sftp(files_folder_name):
    key = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file(RSA_KEY)

    with paramiko.SSHClient() as client:
        client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
        client.connect(pkey=key, **SERVER_CONN)
        with client.open_sftp() as sftp:
            files = sftp.listdir(path=files_folder_name)
            for f in files:
                sftp.remove(f"{files_folder_name}/{f}")
            sftp.rmdir(files_folder_name)
```